# RK4 for stiff IVP

Tags: stiffness

I need a solver of stiff Inital-Value Problems (IVP) in python exploiting RK4 preferably explicit. I have been searching for past few days but could not find it. Following are my queries:

- Does the solver, i.e. any module, exist?
- If no, will it be reasonable to code one? I am asking this because I can't find any reference for using RK4-explicit for stiff problems.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the formulas for explicit RK4 at [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Runge-KuttaMethod.html). Given the simplicity of the expressions it is very reasonable to code one for yourself which is why you may not have found a module.

However, if as you say you are solving a stiff IVP then an explicit Runge-Kutta method is not appropriate (the regions of absolute stability are bounded). Perhaps you should investigate implicit Runge-Kutta methods since there exist A-stable methods of arbitrarily high order.

Answer (score 0):

You can find lots of RK4 codes with many languages in this page

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_method#Python. Good luck!